# database table - data structure design c++

Tags: c++, database-design, data-structures

this may be a dumb question or asked many times, i searched for it but did not find a proper answer.

What is exactly going on when we type on SQL engine

```
"Create table xxxx"
```

how to implement this one in c++, i mean how it creates a variable dynamicalyy "xxxx" and store the data in it. If i queried

```
"select * from xxxx"
```

how it go to variable "xxxx' and get the values. I already seen SQLite and Postgres, i am not able to understand those complex things. Can any one explain it in a simpler way. If possible with a little example. (Note: what ever the sql engine it is).

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to *implement* a database in C++ or do you want to *use* a database in C++? The first is a non-trivial task and the latter, depends on which database server (or embedded) you are using.

Comment: Not the whole database, these statements only - "create table xxxx" - "insert into xxxx values ("1","hai")), "select * from xxxx" - but i would like to do it in a generic way - not hard coding

Comment: You've still not said what your goal is? Let me try again, is your intention that a "user" passes you the string "create table xxxx", and then you parse this and "create" an instance of the structure with the name xxxx? Similarly, you will parse "insert into ..." and handle that in C++ etc.?

Comment: ohh... really sorry.. nim.. yes my goal is like what you said. I want to parse it, if first two words are "create table" then table name is third word, try to create a structure or class(which will be benficiar) for that word, insert values in that one, and select * from that name.

Comment: Can you give me a rough idea or design how to do it by simpler way, i mean not to store data in disks or other things. just my data is roughly 10 rows(suppose) and 10(tables - they may change).

Answer (score 4):

Databases use various disk-based data-structures, such as B-trees, Linear-Hash-Tables, and Heap Files, to store data on disk.  It is an incredibly complex topic that requires a lot of study, but essentially depending on the type of data you want to store (whether it is fixed length or variable length), a common strategy used by many databases is to store variable length data on pages stored in a **[heap file](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dbbook/openAccess/Minibase/spaceMgr/heap_file.html)**.

The heap file is basically a sequence of fixed-length *pages*, each page containing slots for different records.  Pages are stored on disk, but are loaded into memory using a paging sub-system, similar to the way a file-system works.  In order to facilitate quick lookup of records stored on pages, an index structure (usually a B-tree or B+tree, but also possibly a hash table) is used to find the correct page and record number of the record you're looking for stored in the heap file.

The SQL query-engine is layered on top of the underlying data structures.  The query engine parses the query, and then looks up the appropriate records using indexes.  (There's many other facets involved here, but that's the gist of it.)

Needless to say, implementing a relational database in C++ (or any language) requires an enormous amount of work.  If you're really interested, I would recommend reading [Database Management Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072465638).

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server there is an overview starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180978.aspx).

> Objects in the SQL Server database are
>   stored as a collection of 8-KB pages.
>   This section describes the way the
>   pages for tables and indexes are
>   organized, stored, and accessed.

Answer (score 1):

do you have to implement a relational database in c++, if you just want some convenient data structure to store data in multiple index, have a look at [boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)